# How did the United States treat POWs in Vietnam?

Tags: vietnam-war

Did the USA take prisoners of war in Vietnam? Did they administrate POW camps? Or were the South Vietnamese in charge. I know there is a famous photo of a South Vietnamese police officer summarily executing a prisoner.

Comment: I just wanted to add that "prisoner" executed was not a pow he was a nva spy therefore the Geneva convention doesn't apply. It was during the Tet offensive

Comment: The Burns documentary has more on this in episodes 7 (near end, telling the story of a nurse from NY) and 8 (at 13:14). Some prisoners received medical treatment in the field, and some spat on the doctors trying to treat them. There were POW camps in Saigon, 40k N VN and VC soldiers in "4 crowded camps," plus 200k S VN civilians, "many held without trial." There was torture, including electric shocks, waterboarding, and hanging men up.

Comment: You might want to consider including a remark such as "considering they made it alive from surrendering to being registered as a prisoner of war". Body counting could have been an incentive for not taking POWs in the first place, unless they also counted captured and alive enemies.

Comment: What has preliminary research revealed? Have you checked google & Wikipedia?

Comment: @BenCrowell please don't answer in comments.

Comment: remember that geneva convention applies only to  armies in uniform. Spies, infiltrators, non-uniformed saboteurs, do not count and may be killed. The US Army shot German infiltrators/saboteurs in WWII too. If a Vietcong officer forces or convinces a villager to fight against USA or South Vietnam, applying Geneva is not automatic for both of them. It depends on some factors.

Comment: @JoeWierdak plus the spy was executed by the South Vietnamese police, not the US Army.

Answer (score 10):

Focusing just on the Viet Cong, the American's usually transferred them to the custody of the government of South Viet Nam.  This legal analysis identifies some of the flaws in the Geneva Conventions: [Law at War: Viet Nam 1964-1973:](http://www.lawofwar.org/vietnam_pow_policy.htm)

> As combat units of the United States became heavily engaged in the war
>   in 1965, the question arose as to the proper disposition for
>   battlefield captives and others detained by U.S. units during military
>   operations. In 1965 the United States determined to win over to the
>   Vietnamese armed forces all individuals captured by U.S. forces. Such
>   an arrangement is permissible under the Geneva Prisoner of War
>   Conventions, which provide for the capturing power to release
>   prisoners to a detaining power as long as both the capturing and the
>   detaining powers fulfill certain obligations concerning the welfare of
>   the prisoners.
>
> While the legal basis for a transfer of prisoners was sound, carrying
>   out the transfer was beset by serious legal and practical
>   difficulties. The Republic of Vietnam regarded the Viet Cong as
>   criminals who violated the security laws of South Vietnam and who
>   consequently were subject to trial for their crimes. As indigenous
>   offenders, the Viet Cong did not technically merit prisoner of war
>   status, although they were entitled to humane treatment under Article
>   3, Geneva Prisoner of War Conventions. Under Article 12, the United
>   States retained responsibility for treatment of its captives in
>   accordance with the Geneva Conventions even after transfer of the
>   captives to the South Vietnamese. At the same time, the United States
>   was concerned that Americans held captive in North and South Vietnam
>   receive humane treatment and be accorded the full benefits and
>   protection of prisoners of war. In the south, where the government of
>   South Vietnam had tried and publicly executed some Viet Cong agents,
>   there had been retributory executions of Americans by the Viet Cong.
>   In the north, the Hanoi government stated that it would treat captured
>   American flyers humanely, but it would not accord them prisoner of war
>   status as they were "pirates" engaged in unprovoked attacks on North
>   Vietnam. Hanoi repeatedly threatened to try United States pilots in
>   accordance with Vietnamese laws, but never carried out this threat.
>   U.S. policy was for the United States to do all in its power to
>   alleviate the plight of American prisoners. It was expected that
>   efforts by the United States to ensure humane treatment for Viet Cong
>   and North Vietnamese Army captives would bring reciprocal benefits for
>   American captives.
>
> Early in the war there had been some question in the United States
>   command as to whether the struggle against the Viet Cong constituted
>   an armed international conflict as contemplated in Article 2, Geneva
>   Prisoner of War Conventions, or a conflict not of international
>   nature, to which Article 3 would be applicable. With the infusion of
>   large numbers of United States and North Vietnamese combat units and
>   the coming of the Korean, Australian, Thai, and New Zealand
>   contingents of the Free World Military Assistance Forces, any
>   practical doubts as to the international nature of the conflict were
>   resolved. Although North Vietnam made a strong argument that the
>   conflict in Vietnam was essentially an internal domestic struggle, the
>   official position of the United States, stated as early as 1965, and
>   repeated consistently thereafter, was that the hostilities constituted
>   an armed international conflict, that North Vietnam was a belligerent,
>   that the Viet Cong were agents of the government of North Vietnam, and
>   that the Geneva Conventions applied in full. This view was urged upon
>   the government of South Vietnam, which acceded reluctantly, but
>   subsequently came out in full support of the conventions.

[Some powerful photographs](https://incredibleimages4u.blogspot.com/2010/02/american-soldiers-and-vietcong-fighters.html)

[image]

Comment: So, most prisoners were killed after being tortured, correct? Like 80% of all vietnamese captured?

Comment: Your answer doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Lisa: I heard from someone who was there, their unit or squad or whatever you call it tortured and I don't know why anyone would be surprised. Anyone who knows about how police treated suspects in the USA in the 1960s or how we treat prisoners at Gitmo to this very day, for that matter.

Comment: @Jeff: Doesn't make it any better.

Comment: @Lisa impossible to conclude from this text. It doesn't mention either large scale executions, nor torture.

Answer (score 2):

I was assigned to the 50th Medical Co.(Clr) in Long Binh 1965 - 66.  This unit was a second tier medical facility treating VietCong prisoners until they would be well enough to be sent to an RVN POW camp.  The unit also handled U.S. Army prisoners awaiting transfer to CONUS after being convicted of a crime and awaiting transfer prison.  The facility was enclosed with fencing and barbed wire and had (for the VietCong) three wards.  It was guarded by MP's.  The doctors and medics caring for them treated them just like any other patient.  Jokes were made about the "slopes", etc. but since they didn't speak English I think they were not likely too offended.  They got the same food as the troops caring for them, except they got rice with every meal as I remember.  There was never any abuse, torture, etc.  Some became friends with various medics.  They all hated to be released from this facility and be sent to the RVN POW Camps and often re-injured themselves to prevent that.

Comment: Please provide a verifiable source for your claims.

Answer (score 1):

I was the Sgt in charge of the POW camp in Quinon Valley in 1968. No prisoner was abused. Their medical needs were attended and they were fed and sheltered. We had no problems with them. I closed the compound down and all 150 were turned over to Arvn police.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: Right now all we have is a new user making unsourced claims to authority. Let's say I am skeptic of that.

Comment: @DevSolar also something to consider: eye witnesses are often referred to in History as a *primary source*

Comment: @KevinStarmast: If that source can be verified, that is good. If that source can be verified by someone who does *not* have a conflict of interest, that would be even better. If that source cannot be verified, it's useless at best.